# Access DB query not showing in Apache, here's the scriplet in Netbeans i have

Tags: java, jsp, ms-access, jdbc

This is what i have, when i run the jsp file on the browser the only thing i get is the "Report" header but not the query result, please guide me to the right way.

```
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="database.Dba"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center> <h1> Report </h1></center>
     <%
//scriplet
try{

    Dba db =

    new Dba(application.getRealPath("daw.mdb"));
    db.conectar();
    db.query.execute("select usuario from usuarios");
    ResultSet rs = db.query.getResultSet();


    while(rs.next()){
        out.print(rs.getString(1)+ "<br>");

                }
    db.desconectar();

}catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's this `new Dba()` thing doing?

Comment: Is there any error message in the console or log file (e.g. catalina.out if you use Tomcat)? You could also add `out.print("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());` line to the catch block.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek Yes i'm using tomcat and i do get a huge error now that i checked after you told me to. This is the part where it starts.


    `21-Oct-2015 01:08:49.878 INFO [main]     org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 3755 ms
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:ucanaccess://null`





And after i added `the out.print("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());` part i got:          ERROR: null

Comment: @JozefChocholacek So im thinking after checking that error that my mistake might be in this part:

`public void conectar(){
        try {
            Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
            String driver = "jdbc:ucanaccess://";
            dbcon = DriverManager.getConnection(driver+base_datos,"","");
            query = dbcon.createStatement();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }`

Comment: @MelvinChinchila Yes, you are probably missing the JAR file with DB driver. It has to be copied either into the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of your webapp, or into the Tomcat's `lib` folder.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek Weird though, i just doubled checked and all the files are there and i've imported all the jars into my proyects ibraries and still im getting that driver probem :/

Comment: @MelvinChinchila From a quick look at the UCanAccess documentation, I'd say the problem might be that you have to use absolute path to your DB file, e.g. `C:/Users/melvin/project/daw.mdb` instead of just `daw.mdb`. But not sure.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek so i added `Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");`
 to solve the no driver problem and now im getting this ughh :(

`net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::3.0.2 given file does not exist: null
 at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver.connect(UcanaccessDriver.java:258)`